# Populate the sequence numbers when the dates are overlapping

Tags: excel

I am working on an excel task, where I need to mark overlapping dates with series numbers

My excel file consists of **In order** date in "**C Column**" and **Out Order** date in "**D Column**", from this i need to determine overlapping dates and mark them with flag numbers like 1, 2, etc.

**My Struggle**:  I need the sequence numbers where the dates are overlapping, if overlapping not occurs then it should be blank. Below sample shows the output that i need, which i mentioned under Heading "**Series**" column and that should be based on SpID column. If SpID column changes then it should take next serial number.

Formula that i used for overlapping is shown below

My apologies, Please ask any question if you are not able to understand my query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "My Struggle" - indeed. Do some struggling yourself, and post when you have a specific problem you can't overcome rather than asking someone to do it all for you.

Comment: I suspect you will want judicious application of `COUNTIFS` for this...

Comment: SJR, thanks for reviewing my query, Here i have done ovelapping instance with sumproduct  and the formula goes like this IF(SUMPRODUCT((C4<=$D$2:$D$5004)*(D4>=$C$2:$C$5004)*(A4=$A$2:$A$5004))>1,"True",""). But i'm not able to populate the series numbers where i got stuck. i tried the ways i can.

Comment: Chronocidal, can you explain little bit.

Comment: OK good, can you add the formula to your question please as it's not very readable in a comment.

Comment: I have mentioned formula in question. Thanks

Comment: What is 'Overlapping'? When I used the formula almost all are true except the series 37. In your table above can you insert a columns showing expected result you want?

Comment: At a very basic level: to count the number of rows that overlap with this one, it must End after this one Starts, and Start before this one Ends, or `=COUNTIFS(D:D, ">"&C1, C:C, "<"&D1)`.  If you want the overlap sequence number, then you want only the ones that End after this one Starts, and Starts before this one **Starts** instead, `=COUNTIFS(D:D, ">"&C1, C:C, "<"&C1)`.  There are various other adjustments you can make as your requirements change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried you formula for overlapping in Column F. Everything is returned true. So using hypothetical formula `=INT(C2)=INT(D2)` in G Column to return true if both the dates are same.

Once you get your criteria results you can use following formula. This formula in H2 for calculating serial numbers for all true values in Column G. It will return 1 for the first true in column G and incremental numbers for subsequent trues. Enter and copy down the formula.

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($G$1:G2,TRUE)=1,G2=TRUE),1,IF(G2=TRUE,LOOKUP(2,1/($H$1:$H1<>""),$H$1:$H1)+1,""))
```

This how we can calculate serial numbers for any nonconsecutive elements in a column.

[image]

New formula as per your comment below. Enter 1 in E2 and formula in E3 and copy it down

```
=IF(AND(A3=A2,C3<=D2),E2,E2+1)
```

Comment: Im really sorry, I m struggling to get it back. i dont know how to approach it.

Comment: Ok :) got it .. Take your time please.

Comment: Edited my answer with new formula

Comment: Naresh, For understanding i gave blank rows for every overlap. if there are no blank rows between every overlapping (filter all the empty rows and delete them) then this formula should work as is. That is the exact result i need. Thanks a lot for you good heart.

Comment: Can any one help me either with excel formula or with macro code.

Comment: Rajsha, Your question is not clear. You want to number "overlapping" but as per your formula everything is overlapping. So only number 1 will be repeated for all rows. If there are cells no overlapping, the formula above should work.

Comment: Naresh Bhople, 
Actually we have to work on only overlapping date.
That's the reason you see are the dates are overlapping.
1. For Allot# 52291 and 3609 the dates are overlapping with Allot#62010. These slot should be marked as 1.
2. For Allot# 24070 in and out dates are overlapping with Allot# 11500 then these slot should be marked as 2. This continues so on with increment serial number
If you see the Allot# 3609 and 11500 these are not overlapping since there is a date gap. So we are increment +1 to the above number.(which is in column F)
Is this explanation helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210776/discussion-between-naresh-bhople-and-rajsha).

Comment: Answer edited. See the last line. If this is answer, please accept/ tick and close the question.

Comment: It will work id you have sorted the data on A and then C column

Comment: Oh God! Naresh. Sir you did it. thanks a lot. And really forgive me for troubling you sooo much. You are really Genius. Is there any this that i need to do from my end.. Its really a small formula but this solved my struggle. Thank you soo much

Comment: It was a simple formula. :) You could get the answer much earlier if the question was correct. You can keep this in mind for any next question. Cary on, no need to answer this.